# How to view Apple Watch Crash logs on device (without Xcode)

Tags: ios, apple-watch, crash-reports, watchos-4

[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1747/_index.html) link discusses how to obtain crash reports on the iPhone, but I'm unclear once I get to the Analytics data (1) what I'm looking at and (2) specifically I'm trying to trace down the cause of a recent crash of my Apple Watch app, how can I locate this information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some digging, going to Xcode -> Devices and Simulators -> View Device Logs... lists iPhone as well as watch crashes in an easy to read format.

Comment: Is this the same for the physical devices?

Comment: Yes this is for a physical iPhone/Apple Watch

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by installine `sysdiagnose` profile to Apple Watch.

Download the watchOS profile from here:

https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/?name=sysdiagnose

Add it to your iPhone and you will get the choice to choose "Apple Watch" to install it to. Once you install it and click "Done" then you will start seeing Apple Watch logs in Console.app.